# Json mapping auto generated attribute names

Tags: java, json, gson

How can I pragmatically map this objects, attributes inside data object if these names are auto-generated?

[image]

Comment: You can map them in a HashMap..

Comment: thanks Niver, but im fairly new with this. inside {}1 are nested object. can you provide some sample codes i can work with. i am parsing it with gson

Comment: Maybe some code showing your own effort might help to answer. And put JSON as text not as an image. See [howto MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).